# Refactoring Test Units in Angular 4 and Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, refactoring, karma-jasmine

File: `login.component.spec.ts`

- Jasmine, Karma, and Angular 4

Code:

```
// To set up
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// To support the view
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PageLoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('PageLoginComponent', () => {
  let component: PageLoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageLoginComponent>;

  // To Assign
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        PageLoginComponent,
       ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageLoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // To Tear down
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should return true', () => {
    component.login();
    console.log(component.form.errors);
    expect(component.form.errors.invalidLogin).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

For this test to run I need to do all of these imports.

Under the authentication folder, I have got, login component, lock screen, confirmation, forgot password.

I need to write test for each of these components. They are using almost the same imports ( at least the `// set up` part ).

Is there a way that I can put the similar imports in to a shared module then import that one module into the new test?

( Not a good OO design practice, I know that, I am just curious if that is possible )

Thanks in advance.

------------- login.component.ts - In case you need it

```
import { UsernameValidators } from './username.validator';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-page-login',
  styles: [],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class PageLoginComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  // Defining property - For the ease of access
  get username() {
    return this.form.get('username');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.form.get('password');
  }

  login() {
      this.form.setErrors({
        invalidLogin: true
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

I made a `TestModule` then I put all of the imports which will be shared among all of the tests. Inside each spec file I only import what is very specific to that particular test.

( a sample `TestModule` )

`TestModule` exported from `testHelper.module.ts` which is in a folder called `testHelpers`

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ControlMessagesComponent } from './../shared/control-messages.component';
import { DataStub } from './data.stub';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ApiService } from '../service/api.service';
import { MaterialModule, MdNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { DeliveryBoyService } from './../service/delivery-boy.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { StorageService } from './../service/storage.service';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MaterialModule,
        MdNativeDateModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ControlMessagesComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        NgForm,
        StorageService,
        { provide: ApiService, useClass: DataStub },
        FormBuilder,
    ],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ControlMessagesComponent,
        MaterialModule,
        MdNativeDateModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
    ]
})
export class TestModule {}
```

Now in a spec file:

```
import { TestModule } from './../../test-helpers/testHelper.module';
import { CountdownPipe } from './../../pipes/count-down.pipe';
import { ARegistrationService } from './../a-registration.service';
import { ANewFormComponent } from './a-new-form.component';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('ANewFormComponent', () => {
  let component: ANewFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ANewFormComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ANewFormComponent, CountdownPipe ],
      imports: [
        TestModule
      ],
      providers: [
        ARegistrationService,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ANewFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });


  fit('should be created', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

That is. I think this is a very good refactoring. You get to set up the `TestBed` and just get on with the test.

Cheers